# How to use ghs_* token in github?

Tags: github, github-api

I just wanna know what I can do with a ghs_* token? And how I can use this token?
I'm not a developer, but my friend needs help.

I have tried to read about it everywhere, but didn't get the answer that I want.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.